# scrollTo scrolls to the top of the page

Tags: javascript, onload, scrollto

I have the following Javascript code.

When the page is loaded it is scrolled to the right position. When I click on the link to run the function the page scrolls to the top of the page.

How do I fix this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script  type="text/javascript">
            function scroll() {
                window.scrollTo(0, 400)
            }
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body onload="window.scrollTo(0, 400)">
        <img src="a.jpg"/>
        <a href="#" onclick="scroll">comments1</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
onclick="scroll(); return false;"
```

that should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To add a bit more detail, with the `return false;`, the click event continues after the page is scrolled, and the click event follows the `href` to `#`, which is the top of the page.  An alternative way to fix this is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scroll">comments1</a>
```

Returning false is better, IMO, but this would also do the trick.

Comment: You must still *call* the function ("`scroll();`"), not just reference it (`"scroll"`).